# Views aggregation?

Tags: views

I have a view that lists users. These users have skills. Two users are listed multiple times; one user three times; twice with "no skill" and once with the skill they have; another one twice, once with "no skill" and once with the skill they have. If I enable aggregation, skills are gone; if I don't, I get duplicate results. I have tried distinct as well, to no avail. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

What can I do to eliminate this issue?

K.

Comment: Just put in a normal filter to filter on skills, and set it to 'Is not equal to' with Value 'No Skill', or something like that, depending on what type of field your skills are.

Comment: @J.Reynolds As you can see in the screenshot above, some users who aren't listed twice not having a skill is indeed valid.

Comment: @J.Reynolds would an export of the view help? http://paste.debian.net/137807/

Comment: Aggregation with "group results" for the name should group all field for that user together.

Comment: @Neograph734 when I aggregate, group results is default and skills are shown multiple times. Please see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11918318/Screenshot%20from%202014-12-26%2009%3A12%3A41.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some profiles were not showing because their "skills" were missing. When I completed a profile in a way that they have a "skill", it also showed up.

Answer (score 1):

If the skills come from taxonomy terms, you can do as follows.

Choose 'group results' for both title and the taxonomy terms. Then in the taxonomy terms dialog it should show a dropdown to group by 'entity id' or 'taxonomy id'. Choose 'entity id'.

No need to check the boxes.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sooau5vccardovy/Screenshot_2014-12-26-13-06-12_1.jpg?dl=0

(cant embed the image on phone...)

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! I was about to pull out my hair.